# IndexOutOfBound Exception after adding new jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a ComboBox where I can select a Person. After selecting a Person, I want to change my active JPanel with a new one that provides all the Information of the person I selected. But when I change the JPanel I receive an IndexOutOfBoundsException. I'm a newbie but I always thaught that this Error only appears to small Arrays? What did I do wrong?

My first class:

```
 public void initGUI() {
    comboBox1.removeAllItems();

    for (Person personi : listPerson) {
        comboBox1.addItem(personi);
    }
    comboBox1.setSelectedIndex(-1);

    comboBox1.addItemListener(e -> comboBox1Pressed(e));
    frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
    frame.repaint();
    frame.revalidate();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private void comboBox1Pressed(ItemEvent ie) {
    if (ie.getStateChange() == ie.SELECTED) {
        gui_Person.initGUI((Person) ie.getItem());
    }
}
```

And my second one:

```
public void initGUI(Person person) {
    frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
    frame.repaint();
    frame.revalidate();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

The error appears in the second class in this line:

```
frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
```

The stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:492)
at java.awt.Container.remove(Container.java:1217)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.remove(JLayeredPane.java:246)
at java.awt.Container.remove(Container.java:1262)
at javax.swing.JRootPane.setContentPane(JRootPane.java:623)
at javax.swing.JFrame.setContentPane(JFrame.java:698)
at GUI_Person.initGUI(GUI_Person.java:45)
at GUI_Person.initGUI(GUI_Person.java:45)
at GUI_Main.comboBox1Pressed(GUI_Main.java:42)
at GUI_Main.lambda$initGUI$0(GUI_Main.java:32)
```

Comment: *"What did I do wrong?"* For example omitting the stacktrace.

Comment: I'm sorry, Tom! I'm new here on Stack Overflow and I forget it. I'll edit it!

Comment: Your problem is this line `frame.setContentPane(mainPanel)` because Swing tries to remove the former content pane from the internal layered pane, but that pane only has 1 item, not two. Either you're playing around with the layered pane or Swing itself has a problem here. Please try to create a [mcve] so we can reproduce your problem locally.

Comment: Tom, thank you for your answer! This definetly helped me. I'll edit the solution into my question. Next time I'll pay more attention in the example. Thank you for the thread!

Comment: I readded an important snippet from the stacktrace and I moved your answer from the question into an own answer post (see this meta post about this behavior: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278050/editing-self-answer-out-of-question). If you like to get credit for your own answer, you can post it again and I would remove the community wiki, so you would gain reputation post for upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by removing the old panel first and add the new one afterwards:

```
public void initGUI(Person person) {
    frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
    frame.repaint();
    frame.revalidate();

    frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
    frame.repaint();
    frame.revalidate();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the first repaint() and revalidate() if you are going to set the content pane immediately afterwards. And why call repaint() at all if your frame is not yet visible? You probably want to call frame.pack() instead of frame.revalidate().

Comment: @FredK Mind that this code is from OP and extracted from the question. So don't forget to add a `@SovietPanda` in your comment to ask him, or write this comment under the question :). And if OP agrees, then feel free to update this answer to improve it :) (that's why this question is a community wiki).

Comment: @FredK To be honest, I acually don't know it either. Right now I'm more like "If it works, it works" and not studying the reason why you have to do it like this. I found a part of it from another topic and copied it from there. So if you have a better suggestion, then feel free to edit it.